# pgfplots: meta key not working when used in style

Tags: pgfplots

This is a follow up question of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258194) question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Style with meta option
\pgfplotsset{
    myStyleWithMeta/.style={    
        meta=Label, 
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    enlargelimits = true,
    xlabel = {Travel $s$ in mm},
    ylabel = {Force $F$ in N},
    width =120mm,
    height= 80mm,
    title = {Force-Travel-Diagram},
]
\addplot[
    line width=1pt,
    mark=*,
    x=s,
    y=F,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes={font=\small},
    nodes near coords align={anchor=west},
] table
[
row sep=\\,
meta=Label,
% --------------------------------------
% Use of style with meta option
% Comment it out and it works
% --------------------------------------
myStyleWithMeta,
] 
{
s F Label\\
0 0 {$P_0$}\\
0.03 2 {$P_1$}\\
0.7 6 {$P_2$}\\
0.71 5 {$P_3$}\\
1.4 12 {$P_4$}\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the `table` command I use the option `meta=Label`. Where `Label` is a column in my data. Now I tried to put all the options in styles which worked perefctly until I put the `meta` option in a style. Here in the MWE I only put the `meta` option in a style called `myStyleWithMeta`.

I get the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/meta', to which you passed 'Label', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

> Can somebody reproduce the error and maybe has a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `table` sub family to your style. Table options are required to be the subkey of `/table/`. Otherwise `pgfplots` can't understand it and thinks that maybe it is a TikZ key. That's why you have `/tikz/meta` in the error.

Hence you need

```
\pgfplotsset{
    table/myStyleWithMeta/.style={    
        meta=Label, 
    }
}
```

then it works

Comment: Thanks. But is that obvious? In addplot and axes and so on I don't need a special subkey?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner If you look at the manual, you will see every key with its parent subfamily. It is very convenient to have those if you pay attention :P

Comment: Thanks again. I use pgfplots for many years now and never had to use this syntax :).