# Wrong alignment of "nodes near coords" with respect to the bars when some values are negatives

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}% write data file to make make MWE self contained 
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    type,   value,  text
    a,      4.8,    4.8\textsuperscript{\textdagger}
    b,      9.7,    9.7\textsuperscript{\textdagger\textdagger}
    c,      -1.4,   -1.4    
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits={abs=1cm},
    xbar,
    nodes near coords,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    y dir = reverse,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{type},
    ]
    \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex,x=value]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Now imagine I want display the content of the column `text` as label just right of the bars. (As you might guess my objective is to add significance levels to some numbers, and that is the easiest way I have found to do so.)

So, I simply need to add `point meta=explicit symbolic` in the `axis` options and declare `meta=text` in the plot.
For completeness, this is the code with these two things added:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}% write data file to make make MWE self contained 
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    type,   value,  text
    a,      4.8,    4.8\textsuperscript{\textdagger}
    b,      9.7,    9.7\textsuperscript{\textdagger\textdagger}
    c,      -1.4,   -1.4    
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits={abs=1cm},
    xbar,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    y dir = reverse,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{type},
    ]
    \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex,x=value,meta=text]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But here is the result:

[image]

As you can see the anchor of the label changes.

I have tried to play with `nodes near coords align`, for example specifying `horizontal` (which should work?), but it doesn't do anything. Specifying `anchor=west` makes it a bit better, but the negative value is still inside the bar, not outside it:

[image]

Ideally I would like to have the labels of the positive values right of the bars, and the labels of the negative values, left.

In the first case it seems that `pgfplots` knows when the label would be inside or outside the bar, and so having positive or negative values is not a problem. However when the label is pulled from `text`it loses this capability.

I haven't found any questions related to this problem. [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/pgfplots-nodes-near-coords-on-xbar-chart-is-off) is the closest one as it displays a similar issue, but there simply adding `nodes near coords align = horizontal` did the trick.

Comment: Would something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258194/pgfplots-pointwise-positioning-of-explicit-point-meta be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: A workaround would definitely work, but for this particular one I would run into more problems. To use `visualization depends on` I would need to rely on `\thisrow{}` and it does not work when the table is read through `\pgfplotstableread` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354807/filter-rows-from-a-table-read-by-pgfplotstableread) or [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/109/)). I could use the (rather complex) fix proposed in one of these links, or pass the table in the `\addplot` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to my answer in [How to make particular nodes near coords labels bold in a pgfplots bar chart?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372901/how-to-make-particular-nodes-near-coords-labels-bold-in-a-pgfplots-bar-chart/372983#372983)

Instead of having a specific text as meta column, write a number (0,1 or 2 in the example below), and use some `\ifnum`s in `nodes near coords` to decide what is printed based on that number.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}% write data file to make make MWE self contained 
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
    type,   value,  text
    a,      4.8,    1
    b,      9.7,    2
    c,      -1.4,   0    
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.dat}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlarge x limits={abs=1cm},
    xbar,
    nodes near coords={
     \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{text}\of\datatable
       \ifnum \pgfplotsretval=2
         \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}$^{\dagger\dagger}$
       \else
         \ifnum \pgfplotsretval=1
           \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}$^{\dagger}$
         \else 
           \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}
       \fi\fi
    },
    node near coord style={font=\strut}, % for more consistent alignment
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    axis x line       = none,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    y dir = reverse,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{type},
    ]
    \addplot table [y expr=\coordindex,x=value]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If this isn't a viable workaround let me know, I can always delete the answer.

Comment: That's the best workaround I've seen so far!